# SQL Server: Cast bool as integer

Tags: sql-server, integer, boolean, type-conversion

Why does the query:

```
SELECT CAST((column LIKE '%string%') AS INT)+100
```

return

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'*

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can use that expression in a `WHERE` clause but no in a `CAST`.

Comment: SQL Server supports the [bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603) data type.  (Valid values are 0, 1, 'TRUE' and 'FALSE'.)  There is a [boolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx) data type (with values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN), but you cannot get a firm grip on one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because bool is not a type in T-SQL. It does not exist. Boolean expressions are not of type bit. They don't *have* a type - they are only allowed if allowed by the grammar in special places. And yes, this is awful.

```
SELECT (case when (column LIKE '%string%') then 1 else 0 end)+100
```

Comment: Right, copy n paste error. I hope the idea came across though. You can still cast, if you want. It just doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

`CAST` does not evaluate expressions. And any way, how would you case a boolean result to an Int? That would never work.
@usr's answer is the correct way to go.

Comment: Why shouldn't that work? Other languages are pretty fine with and at very least a cast might be seen as syntactic sugar for accepted solution. It's just not supported and that's it. Late reply, I know; just explaining my down-vote...