# Is there a way to use the result of conditions mathematically in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, algebra

I would like to use the result of a test mathematically to decide whether to set a value to a different number if it happens to be zero or whatever.

For example, if I issue something like this: SELECT (1=1)* 100 AS value
I would like value to result as something like 100 or -100 (the latter is how I remember Commodore Basic working).  But instead I get a syntax error on the equal sign.  Is there a way to do this in MSSQL to simplify my queries?

Comment: Use CASE When [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Cast bool as integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056542/sql-server-cast-bool-as-integer)

Answer (score 1):

You could use case when

```
SELECT (case when 1=1 then 1 else -1 end)* 100
```

Also you could use `iif` (Only for SQL Server 2012 or above version)

```
SELECT iif(1=1,1 ,-1)* 100
```